# Converting circular structure to JSON, can't see anything circular

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, filtering

I'm learning back-end web development and the course I'm following includes making a REST API for a system that has "tours". I use MongoDB and Mongoose and everything was fine, I was filtering the query according to the parameters and that went well. But then the instructor wanted to put this filtering process (and other query processes) into a class and access them inside this class. After I've done this, I started getting this error. So I know that you can't convert a circular object to JSON, nor can you stringify such an object. But I don't have any... circular objects. Or at least I don't think so. I'm just a beginner, so forgive my mistakes if you will. Here's the code:

```
const Tour = require("../models/tourModel"); //MongoDB Document Model

class QueryModifier {
    constructor(query, reqQuery) {
        this.query = query;
        this.reqQuery = reqQuery;
    }

    filter() {
        console.log(this.reqQuery);
        const queryObj = { ...this.reqQuery }; //destruct the URL query object into a new object for a hard-copy
        const toBeExcluded = ["page", "sort", "limit", "fields"];

        toBeExcluded.forEach((el) => {
            delete queryObj[el];
        });

        console.log(queryObj);
        let queryStr = JSON.stringify(queryObj);
        queryStr = queryStr.replace(
            /\b(gte|gt|lte|lt)\b/g,
            (matchedStr) => `$${matchedStr}`
        );

        this.query = this.query.find(JSON.parse(queryStr));
        return this;
    }

    sort() {
        if (this.reqQuery.sort) {
            const sortBy = this.reqQuery.sort.replace(/(,)/g, " ");
            this.query = this.query.sort(sortBy);
        } else {
            this.query = this.query.sort("-createdAt");
        }
        return this;
    }

    limitFields() {
        if (this.reqQuery.fields) {
            const fields = this.reqQuery.fields.replace(/(,)/g, " ");
            this.query = this.query.select(fields);
        } else {
            //Default
            this.query = this.query.select("-__v"); //exclude __v
        }
        return this;
    }

    paginate() {
        const page = this.reqQuery.page * 1 || 1;
        const limit = this.reqQuery.limit * 1 || 10;
        const skip = (page - 1) * limit;
        this.query = this.query.skip(skip).limit(limit);

        return this;
    }
}

exports.getAllTours = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const features = new QueryModifier(Tour.find(), req.query)
            .filter()
            .sort()
            .limitFields()
            .paginate();
        const tours = await features;

        res.status(200).json({ //<------ Error's "position" is after the second dot.
            status: "success",
            results: tours.length,
            data: { tours },
        });
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(404).json({
            status: "failure",
            message: e.message,
        });
        console.log(e);
    }
};
```

The error is at the place where I commented with an arrow. And here's the error message:

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Topology'
    |     property 's' -> object with constructor 'Object'
    |     property 'sessionPool' -> object with constructor 'ServerSessionPool'
    --- property 'topology' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at stringify (/Users/mirzabicer/Documents/GitHub/complete-node-bootcamp/4-natours/starter/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1123:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (/Users/mirzabicer/Documents/GitHub/complete-node-bootcamp/4-natours/starter/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:260:14)
    at exports.getAllTours (/Users/mirzabicer/Documents/GitHub/complete-node-bootcamp/4-natours/starter/controllers/tourController.js:84:25)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

I edited that JSON.stringify call to:

`let queryStr = '{ "sort": "price,ratingsAverage", "price": { "gte": "300" } }';`

So there's literally no JSON.stringify call in my code now. But the error I get is EXACTLY the same.

Comment: Does the error tell you which line it happened on?

Comment: It says it's on 84:25. Which is inside the function "getAllTours". It's this part:
`res.status(200).json({`
It's right after the second dot. Also, here's the error: 

`TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Topology'
    |     property 's' -> object with constructor 'Object'
    |     property 'sessionPool' -> object with constructor 'ServerSessionPool'
    --- property 'topology' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)`

Comment: I made the necessary changes in my post for your question and other answers that I might get.

Comment: Since the error suggests the problem is in `tourController.js`, could you post the code in that file as well?

Comment: This code is the `tourController.js` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error suggests the problem is in `tourController.js` on line 84. I guess you are calling `JSON.stringify` on something that is circular on that line. Try removing that `JSON.stringify` call.

It seems `tours` is most likely the problem then. I see it is a `QueryModifier`. I suppose that is probably not the `data` you want to return from `getAllTours`.

You should await the `features.query`, not the `features` itself.

Comment: I edited that JSON.stringify call to:                                    `let queryStr = '{ "sort": "price,ratingsAverage", "price": { "gte": "300" } }';`                  So there's literally no JSON.stringify call in my code. But the error I get is EXACTLY the same.

Comment: tourController.js -> Line 84 is this code's line 84. I have marked line 84 with a comment like this `//<-------`

Comment: I see. It seems `tours` is most likely the problem then. I see it is a `QueryModifier`. I suppose that is probably not the `data` you want to return from `getAllTours`. How does your `Tour`'s `find` look?

Comment: Thank you soooooo much. I can't believe I spent a whole day trying to work this out. "It seems tours is most likely the problem then" saved me from wasting another couple days. If you're interested, let me explain: Tour's find object returns a query. When you await for this query, it finally returns an object so I can use the data in getAllTours. QueryModifier simply makes some operations on this query such as filtering, as you probably are able to understand these as a developer already. But my stupid brain somehow managed to await for QueryModifier object, instead of QueryModifier.query thx!